# Constraining a covariate-path in lavaan

Tags: r, r-lavaan

I have the following `lavaan` model:

```
model <- ' i =~ 1*t1 + 1*t2 + 1*t3 + 1*t4 + 1*t5 + 1*t6 + 1*t7 + 1*t8 + 1*t9 + 1*t10 + 1*t11 + 1*t12 + 1*t13+ 1*t14 + 1*t15 + 1*t16 + 1*t17 + 1*t18 + 1*t19 + 1*t20
s =~ 0*t1 + 1*t2 + 2*t3 + 3*t4 + 4*t5 + 5*t6 + 6*t7 + 7*t8 + 8*t9 + 9*t10 + 10*t11 + 11*t12 + 12*t13 + 13*t14 + 14*t15 + 15*t16 + 16*t17 + 17*t18 + 18*t19 + 19*t20
t8 ~~ 0.01*t8
t17 ~~ 0.01*t17
t18 ~~ 0.01*t18
# regressions
s ~ h_index
i ~ h_index'

fit_UNconstrained <- growth(model, data=growth_data, group = "type")
summary(fit_UNconstrained)
```

Now, I would like to create a model that constraints the paths `s ~ h_index` and `i ~ h_index` to be equal across all groups (`"type"`). How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this works in the same way as it would for adding group-wise constraints to the indicators of a latent factor. And if that's the case, then all you need to do is to add a vector of labels next to the predictor you want to constrain across groups. In your case, you have two parameter estimates you want to constrain, so you'd add two vectors.

The length of the vector is going to depend on the number of groups you have, and the label will be the same for all groups.

Let's suppose you have three groups; then your code would look something like the following.

```r
model <- " 
  i =~ 1*t1 + 1*t2 + 1*t3 + 1*t4 + 1*t5 + 1*t6 + 1*t7 + 1*t8 + 1*t9 + 1*t10 + 1*t11 + 1*t12 + 1*t13+ 1*t14 + 1*t15 + 1*t16 + 1*t17 + 1*t18 + 1*t19 + 1*t20
  s =~ 0*t1 + 1*t2 + 2*t3 + 3*t4 + 4*t5 + 5*t6 + 6*t7 + 7*t8 + 8*t9 + 9*t10 + 10*t11 + 11*t12 + 12*t13 + 13*t14 + 14*t15 + 15*t16 + 16*t17 + 17*t18 + 18*t19 + 19*t20

  t8 ~~ 0.01*t8
  t17 ~~ 0.01*t17
  t18 ~~ 0.01*t18

  # regressions
  s ~ c(v1, v1, v1)*h_index
  i ~ c(v2, v2, v2)*h_index
"
fit_UNconstrained <- growth(model, data=growth_data, group = "type")
summary(fit_UNconstrained)
```

Here the vectors `c(v1, v1, v1)` and `c(v2, v2, v2)` are telling lavaan to constrain these parameter estimates to be equal across groups.

I believe this should do what you have in mind.

Comment: Why are there 3 v1's (or v2's) in each of the constraint?

Comment: I think the reason you have 3 v1's is that you are assuming 3 groups, and I'm assuming 2 groups, correct?

Comment: @histelheim Yes, that is correct. The length of the vectors are determined by the number of groups. If you have two groups, you'd just use `c(v1, v1)` and `c(v2, v2)`.

Comment: makes sense, I was just confounded initially.